# How to convert date and time from kdb server query response using qPython and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, kdb

I have issue converting date and times in the kdb server reply.

I have searched in Internet and here, in StackOverflow, but I could not find a suitable solution. Therefore I need help.

```
from qpython import qconnection
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


query = 'select from trade where date = 2007.02.28, sym = `XXXX'


q = qconnection.QConnection(host=server, port=server_port, username=user, password=server_password, timeout=server_timeout)

q.open()

df = pd.DataFrame(q.sendSync(query))
print(df.to_string())

q.close()
```

The reply is (only header row and the first line of it):

```
      date            time    ex      sym     cond     size          price  stop  corr      seq   src  trpt     participantTime1  rrn     participantTime2   id  exempt
0       2615  15517877000000  b'P'  b'XXXX'  b'T   '      500      27.670000  b' '     0     1095  b'N'  b' ' -9223372036854775808  b'' -9223372036854775808  b''  -32768
```

How to convert date and time? Right now I have 2615 for **date**, which has to be 2007.02.28. The same goes with the **time**. It is 15517877000000, while it should be 0D04:18:37.877000000. (Most probably 0D in time comes from the encoding - a problem which I shall solve later, if needed.). The same goes for **participantTime1** and **participantTime2**

Thank you in advance for anyone's time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas integration and automatic temporal-type casting is supported by the qPython package, which would simplify your issue. You can find the relevant [documentation here](https://qpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html).

The only change you would need to make from your code snippet is to set the `pandas` flag to `True` when instantiating the `QConnection` object:

```py
q = qconnection.QConnection(host=server, port=server_port, username=user,
  password=server_password, timeout=server_timeout, pandas=True)
```

In this case, you also wouldn't need to convert the return value from `sendSync` as q tables will now be represented as pandas dataframes by default:

```py
df = q.sendSync(query)
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer.

It helped with the **date** and **time**, but it returned NaT, NaT and NaN for  _participantTime1_,  _participantTime2_ and _exempt_ correspondingly.

Is it to be expected so?

Comment: `-9223372036854775808` and `-32768` are the internal values for null timespan and short datatypes in kdb+ respectively, so I would expect running this query on the server would also return null values for these columns. With the `pandas` flag set to true, null temporal values will be representend by `NaT` and other null values by `NaN`. This is also covered in the qPython [documentation here](https://qpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html#data-conversions).